# Import python libraries with different dependency versions

Tags: python, numpy, pip, virtualenv

I have 2 python libraries which have different version dependecy  requirement of numpy library. What is ideal way to use both the libraries. I can't use virtualenv as both the libraries have to be used in the same app.

Comment: Which libraries are they? Are the required numpy versions dramatically diffferent?

Comment: Assuming those libs are OSS: select the one which depends on the older version of numpy, check if it works with the version required by the other lib, if yes update the requirement file and submit a patch, else fix it and submit a patch.

Comment: "check if it works with the version required by the other lib" - this might be not so straightforward / involves running regressions tests?